# How can I understand where locate backbone file that extends from plugins?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I'm new of Backbone and I wonder:
How I can understand where I must locate a file that extends from a plugin ?
Example, I want use Backbone.Modal that is a plugin for create easily modals:
https://github.com/awkward/backbone.modal
In their example they simply do:

```
var Modal = Backbone.Modal.extend({...})
```

But if I want have this file in a directory for have more controls on it, where I should place ? inside views ?
Right now I have 3 folders...
 - Collections
 - Models
 - Views
And in my backbone init file I have:

```
window.myApp =
  Models: {}
  Collections: {}
  Views: {}
  Routers: {}
```

And I can easily create a new instance of a view with new myApp.Views.myView()

I tried to add:

```
Modals: {}
```

But I can't access to my modal files anyway...how I should do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library should be stored in your `vendor` folder, or the equivalent folder you use for storing third-party libraries - the same place where you keep libraries like backbone, underscore, jquery etc.

This library attaches `Modal` directly on the `Backbone` object and returns it which you can see right at the end of the script

```
Backbone.Modal = Modal;
return Backbone.Modal;
```

> But if I want have this file in a directory for have more controls on
>   it, where I should place ?

You shouldn't really be altering the code in any third-party library, but you can create an extended base version of it if you like and store it in your `Views` object. Something like...

```
myApp.Views.BaseModal = Backbone.Modal.extend({

    someCustomProperty: 123,

    someCustomMethod: function(){
        return this.someCustomProperty;
    }

});
```

Then any further modals you want can extend from your new base modal view...

```
myApp.Views.LoginModal = myApp.Views.BaseModal.extend({

    // your code for the login modal

});
```

Comment: so BaseModal or LoginModal file should be under views directory, correct ? (this was the question...where I should place my files that extends from Backbone.Modal).
Thank you for the reply.
PS: I have already my third-party libraries in rails vendor directory.

Comment: Yes, I think  base modal / login modal should go in your views directory but keep the backbone.modal in your third-party libraries folder